# Restoring in app purchase issues

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have successfully implemented my ad removal non-consumable in-app purchase. I read that I must also have a "restore" button in my app. I have tried implementing a restore function for the last two days, reading all other posts on stackoverflow and nothing has worked for me. When the restore button is pressed, it requests an email and password as expected but even if I haven't previously purchased the product on that Apple ID it will restore it anyway. Below is the code i am using. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
- (IBAction)RestoreProduct:(id)sender {


[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

NSLog(@"Calling Restore");

_restoreButton.enabled = NO;

_productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Checking for product"];


}




- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
NSLog(@"Calling First Function");
NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
{
    NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    NSLog(@"This Part");
    [self unlockFeature];
    _productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchase Restored!"];
}

}




- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:    (NSError*)error
{
NSLog(@"error");
}
```

EDIT.

Okay, Here is all the code I have from the restore button to the @end.

```
- (IBAction)RestoreProduct:(id)sender {


[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

NSLog(@"Calling Restore");

_restoreButton.enabled = NO;

_productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Checking for product"];


}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
NSLog(@"Calling First Function");
NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
{
    NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    NSLog(@"This Part");

}

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:    (NSError*)error
{
NSLog(@"error");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self unlockFeature];
            _productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Purchase Complete!"];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
             finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
             finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}

-(void)unlockFeature
{
_buyButton.enabled = NO;
[_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased"
            forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[_homeViewController enableLevel2];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
_buyButton.enabled = NO;
_restoreButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a button that calls

```
+ (void)restoreABC
{
    NSLog(@"Restore Purchases");
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

I'm guessing your issue is that you are also calling

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

immediately above:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Delete that first line and you are probably good to go.

EDIT:
Based on the comments below, sounds like the [self unlockfeature] line is the culprit :-)

EDIT #2:

Add

```
    case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        NSLog(@"Feature Previously Purchased");
        [self unlockFeature];
        break;
```

to

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Comment: I removed that line and it still does the same thing. The issue is not that it wont restore the purchase but that is will restore it even if the user hasn't already paid for it.

Comment: So you are testing it by creating a completely new tester in itunes connect?  When the new tester hits the restore button, it automatically unlocks your non-consumables?  Am I understanding you right this time?

Comment: Yes I have created a new tester, gone into the app, tapped restore, entered email and password and then it restores the purchase.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code besides that one line.  Is unlockFeature called out anywhere else in the code?  How are you keeping track of which features have been purchased locally?

Comment: Unlock feature is the actual product that is being restored. I thought the part where I put [self unlockFeature] was the part where it checks if the product has been purchased before. Without the unlockFeature part there it just does nothing.

Comment: Okay so, [self unlockFeature] was the reason why it was giving the product to the user even if they hadn't previously purchased it, but!, after removing that line and the restore button is pressed, nothing happens at all...

Comment: If they haven't purchased anything, nothing should happen.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say even on the user I have that has purchased it, it wont restore it.

Comment: Do you have a completeTransaction method?  Mine calls out [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier]; when transactions are completed.  From here, you would call out your unlockfeatures method.

Comment: Okay, added the code you posted. It never actually reaches that stage though. NSLog goes as far as the "This Part" part of the code when restore button is pressed. Perhaps I am missing a part that calls the payment queue part.